# how can a reproduce a code snippet that looks tabular

Tags: tables, code, code-snippets

Here is the image I cropped from an article. I would like to know how to reproduce the overall structure of this code snippet.

[image]

Comment: This is an algorithm. Did you search for algorithm packages?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Google for: ctan algorithn

Comment: @SebGlav, Thank you! Now that you mention it, I checked algorithm and I found what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an algorithm generated using [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\SetKwInput{Require}{Require}
\SetKwInput{Input}{Input}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Training Procedure of MTCL}
  \Require{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l @{}}
    The feature encoder~$\sigma_\theta$; \\
    Momentum rate~$\alpha$; \\
    Temperature parameter~$\tau$;
  \end{tabular}}
  \Input{Training videos $\mathbf{V} = \{ V_1, V_2, \dots, V_N \}$;}
  \For{each epoch}{
    Initialize a trajectory-center memory bank~$\mathbf{B}$\;
    \For{each mini\_batch}{
      Extract feature maps~$F_b$ by $\sigma_\theta(V_b)$\;
      Detect all targets in~$V_b$ given~$F_b$\;
      Generate multiview appearance vectors by LVS with Eq.~\eqref{eq:first} and Eq.~\eqref{eq:second}\;
      Compute trajectory-level contrastive loss~$L_{tcl}$ with Eq.~\eqref{eq:fourth} and E1.~\eqref{eq:sixth}\;
      Update~$\mathbf{B}$ with Eq.~\eqref{eq:fourth}\;
    }
  }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```